# Pass STDOUT (Bash) to PHP Variable

Tags: php, bash

I want to pass the stdout of a command in bash (ex. `uptime`) to a PHP variable, let's say `uptime` too.
How this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shell_exec` for returning the output of shell commands:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('uptime');
    echo $output;
?>
```

**Result**:

```
18:17  up 12 days, 13:39, 3 users, load averages: 1.80 1.78 1.75
```

↳ http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php